# Spark job failed with "Container killed by YARN for exceeding physical memory limits. "

Tags: apache-spark, memory, memory-management, hadoop-yarn

I run a spark job on spark 3.1 with executor.memory=16G, executor.memoryOverhead=4g and executor.core=5. The job will process a CoGroup join between 2 big tables.

The job is failed with tons of error messages like: Container killed by YARN for exceeding physical memory limits. 21.0 GB of 20 GB physical memory used.

I increase the executor.memoryOverhead to 6g and re-run the job, the job is failed again with tons of error messages like:  Container killed by YARN for exceeding physical memory limits. 22.1 GB of 22 GB physical memory used.

It looks like when I increase the executor memory, the memory used by container is increased too. How to solve error?

Comment: May be this would be helpful: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/emr-spark-yarn-memory-limit

Comment: Since it is a spark job, I can't find yarn-site.xml in my environment. I try to set yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb, yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb, and spark.yarn.am.memory using spark config, but not working.                                                                                          .